# React-router-dom v4 routes and how to display inside children components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First, I would like to confirm that https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial is deprecated and no longer used in favour of https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

I'm using react-router-bootstrap as well because it comes handy for quick building

My problem is that I cannot seem to be able to creates paths such as /services/firstService

I got my **index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('container'));
```

And then my **App.jsx** which is my "principal" component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation/>
                <div className="content">
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/home" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
                    <Route path="/infos" component={Infos}/>
                    <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
                    <Route path="/basic" component={BasicComponent}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The **Navigation** component is simply a react-router-bootstrap/react-bootstrap links

```
export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar>
                <Nav>
                    <LinkContainer to="/home">
                        <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/services">
                        <NavItem eventKey={2}>Services</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/infos">
                        <NavItem eventKey={3}>Infos</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/contacts">
                        <NavItem eventKey={4}>Contacts</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

Now from what I understood I would need to create a link inside my **Services** component which would look like

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/firstService`}>
    firstService
</Link>
```

The Services component is almost empty and this is where I want to display a component {FirstService} and change the path to /services/firstService, same for secondService

```
export default class Services extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super( props );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ul/li
                <Link to={`${match.url}/firstService`}>
                    firstService
                </Link>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/firstService`}>
                    firstService
                </Link>
                ul/li
                <Route path={`${match.url}/firstService`} component={FirstService}/>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/secondService`} component={SecondService}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But then if this is the correct way (that I took from the basic example in react-training) I cannot seem to make it work, or it tells me `ReferenceError: match is not defined`

What's the correct way to make it work ?

Comment: In `Services` you should access `match` with props right? like `this.props.match.url`

Comment: It indeed works and display what I wanted while changing the URL, completely forgot about the props but now I have an another problem, if I reload the page, I get a 'GET http://localhost:8080/services/index_bundle.js 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Not sure what cause this issue. Probably it should be an issue in your webpack setup.

Comment: Thing is, my  historyApiFallback: true is activated in my webpack.config so I don't really know, reload works just fine for normal links but when it's the /services/firstService, I get a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `<Link to={`${match.url}/firstService`}>` is in another component, you have to use `this.props.` to make it work

So you now have `<Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/firstService`}>`

Problem solved but an another error appeared, going to make an another post for it.